# telegram bot posts message at a given time

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have written the following code to send message at certain times in a day. Can someone please suggest alternatives so that I don't have to keep my system running?

```
import telebot
import datetime

bot_token = "(Insert your API Key here)"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)
text = """
<Welcome Texts for Group Members>
"""
times = [3,14]
chat_id = bot.get_chat('@testgroup').id
while 1:
    current_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    hour = current_time.hour
    minute = current_time.minute
    second = current_time.second
    microsecond = current_time.microsecond
    if((hour in times) and (minute==0) and (second==0) and (microsecond==0)):
         bot.send_message(chat_id,text)
```

Comment: Raspberry Pi is always a decent alternative if you're trying to keep something persistently running, though you'd have to keep it online yourself.

Comment: Asking for hosting suggestions is off-topic for SO

Comment: How do you expect your system to perform anything at all if it's not kept running?

Comment: Have you considered using a cron job? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: You have to upload your bot to a Server or VPS otherwise you must keep your computer turned on or as @DylanSmith said you could use a Raspberry Pi.